# Find the true/false status of a checkbox

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-controls

I have the below in a userform. It is supposed to pull a brevity code from a named range for every checkbox in a group box that is checked, and then print it into the required cell in a worksheet.

```
Dim AirExGroup As Frame
Dim TrkExGroup As Frame
Dim OthrExgroup As Frame
Dim cb As Control

Set AirExGroup = Me.AirExGrp        'Contains all Air exception checkboxes
Set TrkExGroup = Me.TruckExGrp      'Contains all Truck exception checkboxes
Set OthrExgroup = Me.OthrExGrp      'Contains all Other exception checkboxes
   
'Airline Exceptions
For Each cb In AirExGroup.Controls
    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
        If cb.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
            'If checked, print Brevity code from Air_Ex list to Air Exception Column
        Else
            'If no boxes checked, print "N/A" in exceptions cell
    End If
  End If
Next cb

'Trucker Exceptions
For Each cb In TrkExGroup.Controls
    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
        If cb.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
             'If checked, print Brevity code from Trk_Ex list
        Else
             'If no boxes checked, print "N/A" in exceptions cell
    End If
  End If
Next cb

'Warehouse Exceptions
For Each cb In OthrExgroup.Controls
    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
        If cb.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
            'If checked, print Brevity code from Othr_Ex list
        Else
            'If no boxes checked, print "N/A" in exceptions cell
        End If
    End If
Next cb`
```

I can't figure out how to get the section that checks which boxes are checked, to pull the correct brevity codes from the code list and print them into the correct cells on the worksheet.

The code below loads that data into an array, but I can't make the two talk to each other.
I found solutions for checking if a group of checkboxes are true or false, and for pulling data from an array.
I haven't found anything here that discusses both working in tandem.

```
Dim Exceptions(1 To 8, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim cb As Shape

For i = 2 To 8
    For j = 1 To 2
        Exceptions(i, j) = Worksheets("List_Data").Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i

MsgBox Exceptions(4, 1) & ", " & Exceptions(6, 1)
```

**----EDIT----**
I may have started to figure it out, but I get

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

The debug points to `If cb.ControlFormat.Value = True`. Any advise on what syntax to use to find the true/false status of the checkboxes in the group box?

```
Set AirCBCap = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("B2") 'Define checkbox caption reference column
Set Air_Ex = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("A2")  'Define brevity code list reference

For Each cb In AirExGroup.Controls
If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
    If cb.ControlFormat.Value = True Then
        For i = 0 To 6
            If cb.Caption = AirCBCap.Offset(i, 0).Value Then 'If checked, find offset in caption name list that matches the checkbox caption     
                If AirCode = "" Then
                    AirCode = Air_Ex.Offset(i, 0)  'Find the offset that matches the offset of the checkbox caption and apply that to "AirCode"
                Else
                    AirCode = AirCode & ", " & Air_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        AirCode = "N/A" 'If no boxes checked, print "N/A" in exceptions cell
    End If
End If
Next cb 
emptyCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = AirCode
```

Comment: What is a "brevity code"? In e.g. airline exceptions, is the code the same for each checkbox that is ticked?

Comment: A brevity code is an understood shorthand for a longer sentence so for example "AA - Flight delayed due to weather", the brevity code is AA, so whenever you would see "AA" associated with a flight, you would understand that there was a weather delay. As for the codes for each box, they are different but sequential and each in their own column on the list data sheet, "AA, AB, AC... etc", "TA, TB, TC... etc." and "OA, OB, OC...etc"

Comment: OK so does that mean that one checkbox has the code AA, another has AB etc? You write "to pull the correct brevity codes from the code list" - how is the correct code determined? Is there a look-up list or similar?

Comment: The check boxes have the format I showed above as the caption so **AA - Flight Delayed due to weather** and there is a named range for each set of brevity codes on a list page, using the format **xxxx_list** where the two letter codes are in ascending alphabetical order, so A2 = AA, A3 = AB... etc. Trk_Ex starts on C2 and Othr_Ex starts on E2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to function using a `For / Next` loop. It's not pretty because there's a lot of Dims and Set ranges that I'm sure can be grouped together into something more elegant but it works the way I want it to so I'll take it for now.

```
Dim emptyCell As Range, AirBoxList As Range, TrkBoxList As Range, WhsBoxList As Range, AirCBCap As Range, Air_Ex As Range
Dim TrkCBCap As Range, WhsCBCap As Range, Trk_Ex As Range, Whs_Ex As Range
Dim shtSel As String, AirBoxName As String, AirCode As String, TrkCode As String, TrkBoxName As String, WhsCode As String
Dim WhsBoxName As String
Dim AirExGroup As Frame, TrkExGroup As Frame, WhseExgroup As Frame
Dim i As Integer

shtSel = sheetslistCB.Value

'Make selected sheet active
Worksheets(shtSel).Activate

Set AirExGroup = Me.AirlineExGrp    'Contains all Airline exception checkboxes
Set TrkExGroup = Me.TruckExGrp      'Contains all Trucker exception checkboxes
Set WhseExgroup = Me.WhseExGrp      'Contains all Warehouse exception checkboxes

Set emptyCell = Worksheets(shtSel).Range("A6") 'SelectFirstBlankCell Use function to determine emptyRow
Set AirCBCap = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("B2") 'Define checkbox caption reference column
Set Air_Ex = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("A2")  'Define brevity code list reference
Set AirBoxList = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("M2") 'Define list of names of Air freight check boxes
Set TrkBoxList = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("N2") 'Define list of names of Truck Check Boxes
Set WhsBoxList = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("O2") 'Define list of names of Warehouse check boxes
Set TrkCBCap = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("D2")   'Define checkbox caption reference column (Trucking)
Set WhsCBCap = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("F2")   'Define checkbox caption reference column (Warehouse)
Set Trk_Ex = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("C2")     'Define Brevity code list reference (Trucking)
Set Whs_Ex = Worksheets("List_Data").Range("E2")     'Define Brevity code list reference (Warehouse)

'Airline Exceptions
For i = 0 To 6
    AirBoxName = AirBoxList.Offset(i, 0).Value
    If Me.Controls(AirBoxName).Value = True Then
        If Me.Controls(AirBoxName).Caption = AirCBCap.Offset(i, 0).Value Then
            If AirCode = "" Then
                AirCode = Air_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value 'Find the offset that matches the offset of the checkbox caption and apply that to "AirCode"
            Else
                AirCode = AirCode & ", " & Air_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value
            End If
         End If
    End If
Next i
emptyCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = AirCode
'Trucker Exceptions
For i = 0 To 3
    TrkBoxName = TrkBoxList.Offset(i, 0).Value
    If Me.Controls(TrkBoxName).Value = True Then
        If Me.Controls(TrkBoxName).Caption = TrkCBCap.Offset(i, 0).Value Then
            If TrkCode = "" Then
                 TrkCode = Trk_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value 'Find the offset that matches the offset of the checkbox caption and apply that to "TrkCode"
            Else
                TrkCode = TrkCode & ", " & Trk_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
emptyCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = TrkCode

'Warehouse Exceptions
For i = 0 To 0
    WhsBoxName = WhsBoxList.Offset(i, 0).Value
    If Me.Controls(WhsBoxName).Value = True Then
        If Me.Controls(WhsBoxName).Caption = WhsCBCap.Offset(i, 0).Value Then
            If WhsCode = "" Then
                WhsCode = Whs_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value 'Find the offset that matches the offset of the checkbox caption and apply that to "WhsCode"
            Else
                WhsCode = WhsCode & ", " & Whs_Ex.Offset(i, 0).Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
emptyCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = WhsCode

Unload Me

End Sub
```